# show post titles below each category wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I want to show a list of post titles in category. like

```
Category 1
post 1
post 2

category 2 
post 1
post 2
post 3

category 3
post 1 
post 2
```

```
    $show_count = 0; 
    $pad_counts = 0; 
    $hierarchical = 1; 
    $taxonomy = 'filter';
    $title = true;
    $description = true;

    $args = array(
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'use_desc_for_title' => $description,
    'title_li' => $title
     );

   $categories=get_categories($args);
   foreach($categories as $category) { 
  echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';


    //display posts
$cat_new = $category->term_id;
$post_args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => $cat_new, 'caller_get_posts' => 0 );


$myposts = get_posts( $post_args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

echo '<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>';

   endforeach; }
```

The above code is just displaying a list of category not post titles below it.

I am just confused that i have read many blogs and post for this but still not done. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code is broken which might break your theme so the posts don't show up. The last line before endforeach lacks closing tags for

and . Also php opening and closing tags are present inside the PHP code, which is very wrong.

```
    $show_count = 0; 
        $pad_counts = 0; 
        $hierarchical = 1; 
        $taxonomy = 'filter';
        $title = true;
        $description = true;

        $args = array(
        'show_count' => $show_count,
        'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'use_desc_for_title' => $description,
        'title_li' => $title
         );

       $categories=get_categories($args);
       foreach($categories as $category) { 
      echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';



    $cat_new = $category->term_id;
    $post_args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => $cat_new, 'caller_get_posts' => 0 );


    $myposts = get_posts( $post_args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

    echo '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';

       endforeach;
endforeach;
 }
```

Comment: the above code outputs the category only not the post titles below category. yea its missing here but its written well in my template page..

Comment: You were also lacking an endforeach. I've updated the code. Everything else looks fine and it should work.

Comment: It shows a parse error pointing to endforeach and when i remove that the error isn't showing anymore.. Please help me

Comment: delete one "endforeach" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very very old and deprecated argument `caller_get_posts` in this code:

```
$post_args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => $cat_new, 'caller_get_posts' => 0 );
```

You should replace with `ignore_sticky_posts`

```
$post_args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => $cat_new, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0 );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<ul>
    <li>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_category(); ?></a> 

    </li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```